# How to run pytest on python script from stdin

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run pytest on a small test that comes from stdin. Something like this:

```sh
$ python -m pytest << EOF
import pytest
def test_x():
    assert True
EOF
```

Or:

```sh
$ python << EOF
import pytest
def test_x():
    assert True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main()
EOF
```

However with either example, pytest reports 0 tests collected. This is the output:

```
========== test session starts ==========
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.5.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.11.0
rootdir: /Users/pablo/
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                   

========== no tests ran in 0.01 seconds ==========
```

I am able to do it with `unittest`:

```sh
$ python << EOF
import unittest
class TestX(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_x(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
EOF
```

Here is the output:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

But how do I achieve it with pytest?

I'm running Python 3.7.2 and pytest 4.5.0

Comment: I don't think this will work, as pytest collects test _files_. `pytest.main()` is a wrapper around the command line tool (in unittest it is basically the other way around), so as long as you don't write the test file, it will not find it (I may be wrong, of course).